# Is there a way to make non-zero values distinct on a colormap in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am making a 2d histogram with values that can range from 0 to about 100 but I want the value of 1 to be easily distinct from 0. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I know you can make custom maps but wasn't sure if there's any way to make 0 values be one color and the rest a simple continuous map.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include minimum reproducible code and what have you tried to do to solve this problem before posting a question here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an ['under'](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_under) color for the colormap and set vmin to 1. That way all cells with a value below 1 will be colored by the 'under' color. The `extend=` option of the [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) show sthe 'under' (and/or the 'over') color. Default a little triangle is used; `extendrect=True` shows it as little rectangle.

If you just want to leave the zero values blank, you can set `cmin=1` which cuts off all the values below 1.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy

x = np.random.randn(10000).cumsum()
y = np.random.randn(2000, 5).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

cmap = copy.copy(plt.get_cmap('hot'))
cmap.set_under('turquoise')
_, _, _, hist1 = ax1.hist2d(x, y, bins=(50, 30), cmap=cmap, vmin=1)
ax1.set_title('Using $vmin$ and $set_under$')
plt.colorbar(hist1, ax=ax1, extend='min', extendrect=True)

_, _, _, hist2 = ax2.hist2d(x, y, bins=(50, 30), cmap='inferno', cmin=1)
ax2.set_title('Using $cmin$')
plt.colorbar(hist2, ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]